# Handling PHP errors with $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] reliable?

Tags: php, security, reliability

Is using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for proper automatic handling of errors reliable?

I'm thinking about using it to automatically disable the display of any PHP errors, show a general "Oops, there wen't something wrong." error to the user and log them internally instead, **if** the user's IP address is **not** found in the white list.

The white list would contain the localhost IP and any other IP adresses such as my home PC.

But if people are able to fake `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` by setting it to whatever value they want, then I don't think this would be a good idea.

Comment: Why not just set it so that a generic error is shown to everyone, but the specific error is logged to a file or e-mailed to you? You can use a live/development constant and an IF statement if you want to see errors while you code the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the address taken from the three-way confirmed TCP handshake. It's pretty darn robust. To fake it you have to fake the actual underlying TCP/IP connection, which is usually a tall order.

What I would be concerned about instead is changing IPs. `127.0.0.1` is probably pretty safe, but your home IP *may* change eventually and somebody else may get it assigned. This may not be a large problem, or it may be. Or you may appear to have the same IP as a large number of other users, with ISPs switching to carrier grade NAT over time.

All in all, using IPs at all as an identification system is flaky. IPs are an implementation detail of a data transport mechanism, nobody has ever said anything about IPs being suitable for internet-wide identification of users. I'd at least pair it with a secret cookie that needs to be set or a regular authentication that needs to have been established.

Comment: I've seen issues with `REMOTE_ADDR` when there is a reverse proxy in front of the application. In that case, the `REMOTE_ADDR` is the one from the proxy, not the expected one from the client.

Comment: You're basically confirming my last paragraph. :)

Comment: Yes indeed! I just wanted to point out a real life scenario which should be taken into account.